# When selecting, it is this weird select tool and I dont know how to make it select with a click

Tags: interface

When selecting, it is this weird select tool and I don't know how to make it select with a click. How would I fix this?

[image: selection tool is buggin]

Comment: You are on Lasoo select. Press W to toggle through select modes until the cursor in the top left of the viewport is an arrow with a dotted box around it again (box select is default).

Comment: Thank you so much @ChristopherBennett !!

Answer (score 2):

You are on Lasoo select. Press W to toggle through select modes until the cursor in the top left of the viewport is an arrow with a dotted box around it again (box select is default). – Christopher Bennett